# aggregate operation coming as null in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
Inventors
    .aggregate([{
            $match: filter
        },
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": {
                    "store_id": "$store_id"
                },
                stockAmount: {
                    $sum: {
                        $multiply: ["$intProductQty", "$dblMRP"]
                    }
                },
                storeValue: {
                    $sum: "$intProductQty"
                },
            }
        },
    ])
    .exec(function(err, stock) {
        return res.send(stock);
    });
```

**schema**

```
{
        "store_id" : "BST000433",
        "strProductCode" : "9000000064775",
        "dblMRP" : 25,
        "intProductQty" : 1,
}
```

I initailized these fields(intProductQty, dblMRP, strPurchasePrice) as integer. But when I execute above command, I'm getting that three values(stockAmount, purchaseAmount, storeValue) as null.

Comment: Can you update your post to include your schema and a sample document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is still possible that some of those values are not set, you could check if they are null with [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) and set them to 0 for those calculations in a `$project` step after the `$match`:

```
$project: {
    intProductQty: { $ifNull: [ "$intProductQty", 0 ] },
    dblMRP: { $ifNull: [ "$dblMRP", 0 ] },
    strPurchasePrice: { $ifNull: [ "$strPurchasePrice", 0 ] }
},
```

Also, I guess it's not your case, but you could filter out those that are not numeric with [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/):

```
$match: {
    intProductQty: { $type: "number" },
    dblMRP: { $type: "number" },
    strPurchasePrice: { $type: "number" }
},
```